# Access error "No Current Record" when printing reports via timed macro, but not when running the macro myself

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database with linked tables to Excel spreadsheets I receive daily. (Rule in place to watch for these spreadsheets in my email and save off to OneDrive).

I have an Access macro to print PDF reports and save to SharePoint.

If I run the macro from Access, it runs fine.  If I use a BAT file in the Task Scheduler, I get the "No Current Record" error.

This process worked for several years when I stored the database and spreadsheets in a shared network drive.  But since moving the process to OneDrive, I get the above error.

I've search here but have not found an answer.

Comment: Where is your MS Access database located at? OneDrive?

Comment: Correct, the Access database and the Excel Spreadsheets are all contained in a folder within OneDrive.

Comment: won't work using OneDrive. I'd move back to using a shared network drive. Did you split your Access file in frontend and backend?